# Is there a limit for devices where I can download my purchased apps?

Tags: ipad, accounts

I'm thinking about renting an iPad for use. And I would like to know if I can put my password to download my apps every time I rent an iPad, or is there a limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download any app and other media purchased with your apple ID to a new device - as long as you authorize your new device with that apple ID.

This is what the [official Apple documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4627) says:

> Your Apple ID can have up to **10 devices and computers (combined)**
> associated with it. Each computer must also be authorized using the
> same Apple ID. Once a device or computer is associated with your Apple
> ID, you cannot associate that device or computer with another Apple ID
> for 90 days. You can view which devices or computers are currently
> associated, remove unused devices or computers, and see how long
> before they can be associated with a different Apple ID from the
> Account Information page in iTunes on your computer.
>
> Last Modified: November 14, 2011